# Different select command in a single button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to give multiple select commands in single button.
 Example:
  Datewise search,name wise,Product wise search in a single show Button.
  But this search can be random like either name wise search alone can be done 
  or name and product wise search can be done.
  But this should done in a single show button only..
  Plz help me with a example code..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a coding doubt,this is more likely a logic doubt,For this you have lot of options here you can perform some SQL Query concatenations Or some `If..else...elseIf` statements,something like this :

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

                    if (ddpcustomer.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddpproperty.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        DataSet ds1 = Tbl_MasterBooking.getDetailsforBookingSummaryWithoutStatusCheckinDate(inputField.Text, inputField1.Text, userId, Cid);
                        GVBookingSummary.DataSource = ds1;
                        GVBookingSummary.DataBind();
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                    else if (ddpcustomer.SelectedIndex != 0 && ddpproperty.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        DataSet ds1 = Tbl_MasterBooking.getDetailsforBookingSummaryWithoutStatusWithCustNameCheckinDate(inputField.Text, inputField1.Text, userId, Cid,ddpcustomer.SelectedItem.Text);
                        GVBookingSummary.DataSource = ds1;
                        GVBookingSummary.DataBind();
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                    else if (ddpcustomer.SelectedIndex != 0 )
                    {
                        DataSet ds1 = Tbl_MasterBooking.getDetailsforBookingSummaryWithoutStatusWithPnameCheckinDate(inputField.Text, inputField1.Text, userId, Cid, ddpproperty.SelectedItem.Text);
                        GVBookingSummary.DataSource = ds1;
                        GVBookingSummary.DataBind();
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                    else if (ddpcustomer.SelectedIndex != 0 && ddpproperty.SelectedIndex != 0)
                    {
                        DataSet ds1 = Tbl_MasterBooking.getDetailsforBookingSummaryWithoutStatusWithPnameandCustNameCheckinDate(inputField.Text, inputField1.Text, userId, Cid, ddpproperty.SelectedItem.Text, ddpcustomer.SelectedItem.Text);
                        GVBookingSummary.DataSource = ds1;
                        GVBookingSummary.DataBind();
                        GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do search based on One filter you'd better use a DropDownList and search based on the selected value or ... but if searching in multiple data collections is your doubt I'll provide you a code snippet below :

```
    private class Product 
    {
        public string Name;
        public double Price;
        public string ToString()
        {
            return Name + " : " + Price.ToString() + "$";
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        names.Add("Jack");
        names.Add("John");
        names.Add("Nick");
        names.Add("Rock");

        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product { Name = "Laptop", Price = 1000 });
        products.Add(new Product { Name = "Tablet", Price = 750 });
        products.Add(new Product { Name = "Rock", Price = 1 });

        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now);
        dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

        lblOutput.Text = "";

        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            if (name == txtSearch.Text)
                lblOutput.Text += name + "[Name] ";
        }
        foreach (Product product in products)
        {
            if (product.Name == txtSearch.Text)
                lblOutput.Text += product.ToString();
        }
        foreach (DateTime date in dates)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(txtSearch.Text, out dt))
                if (date == dt)
                    lblOutput.Text = date.Date.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
```

Also if you want to stop searching as soon as you've found a match, you can put a `return` after each match-found code block, for example:

```
if (name == txtSearch.Text)
    { lblOutput.Text += name + "[Name] "; return;}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with sajanyamaha, this is a logic doubt and that's why I didn't use sql or asp.net code in my answer, you need to know what you want to do, then there will be no difference whether you use a database or a .txt file, windows application or asp.net web application, it's the matter of knowing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would do.You may setup the options you like.

```
    public class Parameters
    {

        //Properties.
        public string CompanyName
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public string ProductName
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public string Design
        {
            get;set;
        }

        public string Size
        {
            get;set;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Parameters para = new Parameters();
        if (cbxCompanyName.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
            para.CompanyName = "'" + this.cbxCompanyName.Text + "'";

        }
        if (cbxProductName.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
            para.ProductName = "'" + this.cbxProductName.Text + "'";

        }
        if (cbxDesign.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
        {
            para.Design = "'" + this.cbxDesign.Text + "'";

        }
    }

    public void test(Parameters paras)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(source);
            con.Open();

            string select;


            select = "SPGetSaleRegCulture ";

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", paras.CompanyName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product", paras.ProductName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Design", paras.Design);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", paras.Size);

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            da.Fill(ds, "SaleRegister");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you're going to use `string where` in SQL then you need to check for sql injection.

Comment: i change the `where clause` with parameters